# Show that eigenvalues of $A, B$ and $AB$ are symmetric about origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> If $A$ and $B$ are two symmetric non-singular $n\times n $ matrices satisfying $AB+BA=$**0**, show that eigenvalues of $A, B$ and $AB$ are symmetric about origin.

I don't know when eigenvalues of matrices are symmetric about a point. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. I have edited.

Comment: @WillJagy Please write it in more details. Why you have assumed A as diagonal. If A is diagonal, then I don't understand what can be said about B.

Comment: @rama_ran;Please check if my answer suits you

Comment: Are $A,B$ square matrices?@rama_ran

Comment: @BenStokes Yes they are square matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Eigen values of $A$ are symmetric about the origin means that if $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$ then $-\lambda$ is also an eigen value of $A$.

Since $A$ is symmetric so all the eigen values of $A$ are real.

Let $\lambda $ be an eigen value of $A$ corresponding to eigen vector $v(\neq 0)$.

Then $Av=\lambda v$.

Now $AB+BA=0\implies AB=-BA$

Then $Av=\lambda v\implies B(Av)=\lambda (Bv)\implies (-AB)v=\lambda (Bv)\implies A(Bv)=(-\lambda) Bv$

*To check that $Bv\neq 0$*

Since $B$ is non-singular,so $v\neq 0\implies Bv\neq 0$

So $ (-\lambda) $ is an eigen value of $A$ corresponding to eigen vector $Bv$.

**NOTE**:Since $A,B$ are symmetric so $(AB)^T=B^TA^T=BA$

Also for any matrix $P,P^T$ have the same eigen values.

Now $AB(v)=\lambda v\implies (-BA)(v)=\lambda v\implies BA(v)=(-\lambda )v \implies (-\lambda ) $ is an eigen value of $BA\implies (-\lambda ) $ is an eigen value of $AB$(since $(AB)^T=BA)$

Comment: Yes, you have proved that eigenvalues of A are symmetric about origin. Also one have to show that eigenvalues of B and AB are symmetric about origin. Would you please prove the last part (i.e eigenvalues of AB are symmetric about origin)?

Comment: Is it difficult ?$AB(v)=cv\implies (-BA)v=cv\implies BA(v)=(-c)v$

Comment: You have assumed AB has eigenvalue c and proved that BA has eigenvalue -c. But one has to show that AB has eigenvalue -c.

Comment: Please check the last calculation for AB

Comment: You wrote λ is an eigen value of $AB \implies AB(v)=λv \implies (λ) $ is an eigen value of A corresponding to eigen vector Bv. How $AB(v)=λv$  implies (λ)  is an eigen value of A. Rather $ (λ) $ is an eigen value of A corresponding to eigen vector Bv  if one can prove $A(Bv)=λ(Bv)$, is it not

Comment: I would be greatful if you kindly elaborately prove for the case AB as you have nicely proved for A.

Comment: @rama_ran;Please check my edits ;Do you need more justifications

Comment: nothing more. its all right.