# A problem regarding eigenvalues symmetric about origin

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[Show that eigenvalues of $A, B$ and $AB$ are symmetric about origin.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012990/show-that-eigenvalues-of-a-b-and-ab-are-symmetric-about-origin) I am doing this problem but I cann't think eigenvalues of $A$ if order of $A$ is odd.In $3*3$ matrices say these are $x,y,z$.From the result we take $y=-x$  but what  about the 3rd eigenvalue?To make it symmetric we cann't take it $0$  as $A$ is nonsingular.Same problem occurs  for $5*5, 7*7, 9*9......$.How can I overcome this confusion or problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it does not work for odd dimensions. Note that the matrix $AB$ is skew-symmetric as $(AB)^T=B^TA^T=BA=-AB$. Then [it must be singular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795160/odd-dimensional-skew-symmetric-matrix-is-singular-even-in-a-field-of-characteri). It contradicts to the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are non-singular.

Comment: @A.T. thanks,I had to think that skew symmetric argument,That problem is very familer in many exams and I found it in my text book.So there is no fault in the given problem.Probably by defining a set of scalers symmetric about the origin we assume that the given set has $2n$  elements in which there are $n$ pairs  of elements and each pair contains $2$ elements  of same mgnitude but opposite sign.Am I corect?

Comment: @SubhajitSaha I cannot say. It may be part of the problem to rule out odd $n$ since there are no nonsingular symmetric $A$, $B$ of odd size satisfying $AB+BA=0$.